# Как парсить историю продаж Steam?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, steam

Пишу парсер торговой площадки steam. Нашел запрос который возвращает масивный список json с историей продаж предмета за весь период времени. Как можно вытащить из данного масива, данные за определённый промежуток времени, месяц, неделя или за определенную дату?

```
import steam.webauth as wa
user = wa.WebAuth('login')
session = user.cli_login('password')
session.get('https://store.steampowered.com/account/history')

link = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=DE&currency=3&appid=440&market_hash_name=Specialized%20Killstreak%20Brass%20Beast'

resp = session.get(link)
result = resp.json()
print(result)
```

Ответ:

```
{'success': True, 'price_prefix': '$', 'price_suffix': '', 'prices': [['Nov 27 2013 01: +0', 16.99, '1'], ['Nov 29 2013 01: +0', 17.205, '2']....
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно для данной задачи это over-engineering, но можете попробовать pandas или Vaex. Они предоставляют Sql-подобные функции поиска, для данных, которые находятся в ОЗУ вашего компьютера. Используя, например, pandas вы можете написать такой код для промежутка времени:

```
mask = (df['date'] > '2000-6-1') & (df['date'] <= '2000-6-10')
```